# Reuse component (Angular)

Tags: html, angular, components

I created a component in angular and it works fine when I have one per document. However when I have more than one this creates and odd behavior where the last variables affects both instances of the component.

This is the html for the component.

```
<div class="thumbnail-div" id="top">
    <img id="img" class="img" src="{{image}}" alt="">
    
    <p id="text" class="text">
      
      <a id="link" class="link" href={{link}}>{{title}}</a><br>
      <i id="ita" class="itaics">By {{author}}</i>

    </p>
</div>
```

This is the parent html

```
<thumbnail 
    title={{articles[0].title}}
    author={{articles[0].author}}
    image={{articles[0].img}}
    link="/#/articles/{{articles[0].date}}"
    color='transparent'
    pos='right'
    long=true
    >
</thumbnail>
```

ts file

```
import { Component, ContentChild, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, TemplateRef, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'thumbnail',
  templateUrl: './thumbnail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./thumbnail.component.css'],
  
})
export class ThumbnailComponent implements OnInit {

 

  @Input() width: string;
  @Input() height: string;
  @Input() img_width: string; 
  @Input() img_height: string;
  @Input() text_width: string; 
  @Input() text_height: string;
  
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() author: string;
  @Input() image: string;
  @Input() link: string;
  @Input() color: string;
  
  @Input() fontSize: string;
  @Input() ita_fontSize: string;
  @Input() left: boolean;
  @Input() right: boolean;
  @Input() bottom: boolean;
  @Input() top: boolean;
  @Input() move_v: string;
  @Input() move_h: string;
  @Input() padding: string;
  @Input() pos: string;

  @Input() long:boolean;
  @Input() text: boolean;
  @Input() short:boolean;
  @Input() thumbnail: boolean;
  
  

  constructor() {

    
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    /*

    $('#top').width(this.width);
    $('#top').height(this.height);

    $('#img').width(this.img_width);
    $('#img').height(this.img_height);

    $('#text').width(this.text_width);
    $('#text').height(this.text_height);
    $('#text').css('background-color', this.color);
    $('#text').css('font-size', this.fontSize);
    $('#text').css('padding', this.padding);
    
    if(this.left){
      $('#text').css('left', this.move_h);
    }else if(this.right){
      $('#text').css('right', this.move_h);
    }
    
    if(this.bottom){
      $('#text').css('bottom', this.move_v);
    }else if(this.top){
      $('#text').css('top', this.move_v);
    }
    

    */

    if(this.long){
      this.longStyle();
    }else if(this.text){
      this.longTextStyle();
    }else if(this.short){
      this.shortStyle();
    }else if(this.thumbnail){
      this.cardStyle();
    }

  }


  longStyle(){

    /**
     * 
     * height="300px"
    
    img_width="100%"
    img_height="100%"

    fontSize="30px"
    right=true
    move_h="0px"

    bottom=true
    move_v="100px"
     */

    $('#top').width('100%');
    $('#top').height('500px');

    $('#img').width('100%');
    $('#img').height('100%');
    $('#img').css('filter', 'brightness(50%)');

    //$('#text').width('200px');
    //$('#text').height('300px');
    $('#text').css('background-color', this.color);
    $('#text').css('color', 'aliceblue');
    $('#text').css('font-size', '30px');
    $('#ita').css('font-size', '20px');
    //
    


    if(this.pos == 'left'){
      $('#text').css('left', '100px');

    }else if(this.pos = 'right'){
      $('#text').css('right', '100px');
    }
    
    
    $('#text').css('bottom', '50px');
    
    

  }

  longTextStyle(){

    
    /**
     * 
     * height="300px"
    
    img_width="100%"
    img_height="100%"

    fontSize="30px"
    right=true
    move_h="0px"

    bottom=true
    move_v="100px"
     */

    $('#top').width('80%');
    $('#top').height('600px');
    $('#top').css('margin', '0 auto');

    $('#img').width('100%');
    $('#img').height('70%');
    $('#img').css('filter', 'brightness(50%)');
    
    $('#link').css('pointer-events', 'none');
    $('#ita').css('display', 'none');

    $('#text').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    $('#text').css('padding', '20px');
    
    $('#text').css('background-color', this.color);
    
    $('#text').css('font-size', '20px');
    $('#ita').css('font-size', '15px');
    
    $('#text').width('80%');
    $('#text').css('margin-left', '50px');
  
    //$('#text').css('right', '100px');
    $('#text').css('bottom', '70px');
  }

  shortStyle(){

    /**
     * 
     * height="300px"
    
    img_width="100%"
    img_height="100%"

    fontSize="30px"
    right=true
    move_h="0px"

    bottom=true
    move_v="100px"
     */

    $('#top').width('100%');
    $('#top').height('400px');

    $('#img').width('80%');
    $('#img').height('100%');
    $('#img').css('filter', 'brightness(50%)');
    

    $('#text').width('250px');
    $('#text').css('vertical-align', 'middle');
    $('#text').height('250px');
    $('#text').css('padding', '25px');
    
    $('#text').css('background-color', this.color);
    
    $('#text').css('font-size', '25px');
    $('#ita').css('font-size', '15px');
    //
    


    if(this.pos == 'left'){
      $('#img').css('right', '0px');
      $('#text').css('left', '60px');

    }else if(this.pos = 'right'){
      $('#text').css('right', '100px');
    }
    
    
    $('#text').css('bottom', '50px');
    
    
  }

  cardStyle(){

    /**
     * 
     * height="300px"
    
    img_width="100%"
    img_height="100%"

    fontSize="30px"
    right=true
    move_h="0px"

    bottom=true
    move_v="100px"
     */

    $('#top').width('300px');
    $('#top').height('300px');

    $('#img').width('100%');
    $('#img').height('70%');
    $('#img').css('filter', 'brightness(50%)');
    

    
    $('#text').css('padding', '10px');
    
    $('#text').css('background-color', this.color);
    
    $('#text').css('font-size', '18px');
    $('#ita').css('font-size', '15px');
    //
  
    //$('#text').css('right', '100px');
    $('#text').css('bottom', '20px');
  }
```

Basically I want to reuse the same component with different styles and variables. I'm only using a few variables in this example, not all.
I have seen some explanations which were not clear at all. I decided to ask so I could get an explanation for my particular example. I really would appreciate an answer to this. Thank you guys.

Comment: which variable and in which way affects other instances?

Comment: Can you be more specific which variables and add the part that you have the @Input variables so maybe what you are doing ?

Comment: ok i will edit it

Comment: Done. I included the ts file for the component

Comment: Sorry to say that but you are doing it entirely wrong. You are using jQuery inside of Angular which will lead to many errors. In this specific case  you have IDs in your template  like #text #img and manipulating them in different instances. But IDs are meant to be unique so this will be one of your problems.

Comment: You really need to read or learn how to do property binding in angular, the problem here is u r using id selector to pick an element and applying the style even if u have multiple <thumbnail> component it will apply only to the first <thumbnail>. This should not be written in this way at all in angular.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

parent.html

```
<div class="thumbnail-div" id="top">
    <img id="img" class="img" src="{{image}}" alt="" [ngStyle]="myStyle">
    
    <p id="text" class="text">
      
      <a id="link" class="link" href={{link}}>{{title}}</a><br>
      <i id="ita" class="itaics">By {{author}}</i>

    </p>
</div
```

parent.ts

```
@Input() myStyle: any;
```

child.html

```
<thumbnail 
    title={{articles[0].title}}
    author={{articles[0].author}}
    image={{articles[0].img}}
    link="/#/articles/{{articles[0].date}}"
    color='transparent'
    pos='right'
    long=true
    [myStyle]= "newStyle"
    >
</thumbnail>
```

child.ts

```
newStyle: any;

onInit() {
 this.newStyle = {
   backgroundColor: 'red';
}
```